# How do I launch an application with a specific JDK?

Tags: macos, applications, java

I'm on Sierra, and I have one legacy application that requests Java 6 to run. I have Java 7 installed, and I've also installed Java SE 6 from Apple, but I'm not sure how to force the application to use it.

When I launch it now, it does not launch properly, although the process seems to have started:

```
$ ps -ef | grep Java
501   572     1   0 11:29PM ??         0:04.63 /Applications/Memoir'44 Online.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
```

There may be some subtleties with JavaApplicationStub and plists that I don't understand, but in any case the application never gets beyond initial startup (drawing a blank window), and does not function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a support article from that game's developer addressing an issue where ["the game freezes at start-up (blank screen)"](https://asmodee.helpshift.com/a/memoir-44-online/?s=general&f=macos-x-the-game-freezes-at-start-up-blank-screen-since-i-upgraded-to-high-sierra-macos-10-13&l=en). It involves installing Java 1.6 (as you've done) and manually updating a library file, `libjogl_awt.jnilib`. However that article says the issue occurs when "[upgrading] to High Sierra", so this might not be what's causing your issue if you're still running Sierra.

Comment: The one other thing that people might need to do (I had to do it): Update the certificates used by Java 1.6. There's a page for that as well:

https://asmodee.helpshift.com/a/memoir-44-online/?l=en&s=general&f=macos-x-the-game-says-it-cannot-connect-to-the-servers&p=all

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling Java 7? (Even if this works, it might not be a feasible workaround if you need Java 7 or later for running other programs; I suggest trying my other answer first.)

Comment: That's right, I didn't want to remove later Java versions, but see my comment to you other answer.